# table with id and external css stylesheet will not work or format

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I'm trying to format using my external style sheet. I wanted to add some padding to the whole table and maybe specific the text alignment. The page is:

Its under the featured vehicles section.

Here is my css:

```
table#featured{
text-align: center;
}

table#featured img{ 
border: none;
}

table#featured td{
border: solid #FFFFFF 3px;
}
```

Html:

```
<table id="featured">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='/3/scripts/image_view.php/1_1.jpg?width=100&amp;image=/3/images/autos/1_1.jpg' alt='' />
            <br />127 Mazda RX7
            <br />12000.00
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After I upload it and I go look at the style.css file the css is not there. Its driving me crazy. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Joe

Comment: make sure you have included external css reference on your page.

Comment: When you say the css isnt there...do you mean the .css file is blank
?

Comment: If I pull up the style sheet http://www.northcoastautos.net/3/style.css
The section where I have my css reffering to the table is not there. There is just some extra blank lines.

Comment: Try refreshing it, it might be a caching issue.  When I initially loaded it, there were no results for searching for the word *table*.  When I refreshed it and searched again, your code was there.

Comment: Cleared my brower cache, restarted my browser, still don't see the css when I use my developer tools and view the style sheet. I did connect remotely to the file through EditPlus and verify that the css is there. ugh...

Answer (score 3):

You can write the css like this

```
#featured td{
text-align: center;
padding :5px;
}

#featured td{
border: solid #FFFFFF 3px;
}

#featured td img{
border: none;
}
```

and obviously link the external style sheet to the main html page.. :)

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but the code for the table is part of a PHP Require.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link to the external css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Make sure to add ../ to the mystyle.css, that will go up one folder.

Comment: The temporary page is in http://www.northcoastautos.net/3/home.php and so is the style sheet http://www.northcoastautos.net/3/style.css

Comment: I just saw your comment on the top answer. Can you post your php code, or try to include the domain name<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="northcoastautos.net/3/style.css">